# Datatable row count not working with search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

In the view the code is working fine and showing me the count and result. Also on search. However when I search any word I want that count according to the search result but in my case its showing me total count of the all price fields. It's not showing the current search result count. Can anyone please help me?

My Datatable code for custom search and count of last two fields:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
        extend: "excel",
        className: "darse"
    },{
        extend: "print",
        className: "ddf"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Is there Any solution ??? when i put this code in to searchbox keyup function its quiet working but generating the multi value

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQGvoy Its showing me filtered results. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set `search: 'applied'` in the [`selector-modifier`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) of the  [`column`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) method.

```
$('<p>' + table.column(6, {
    page: 'current',
    search: 'applied'
}).data().sum() + '</p>').prependTo('#demo');
```

You are also calling the sum only once after the inital draw. Move the call to sum to the [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback).
Below is an example:

```js
$.fn.DataTable.Api.register('column().data().sum()', function() {
  return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
    var x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
    var y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
    return x + y;
  }, 0);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      var api = this.api();
      $('<p>' + api.column(1, {
          page: 'current',
          search: 'applied'
      }).data().sum() + '</p>').prependTo('#demo');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span id="demo" />
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gamma</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working.. i tried but not working with search result

Comment: showing the same result its showing me total of the fields not showing the total of fields after search

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use page.info() API. `table.page.info().recordsDisplay` gives the displayed records, even if table is filtered, this gives the currenlty displayed records.

```
const dataTableConfig = {
   "scrollX": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
        extend: "excel",
        className: "darse"
    },{
        extend: "print",
        className: "ddf"
    }]
};
const table = $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableId').dataTable({
        ...dataTableConfig
    });
})
console.log(table.page.info().recordsDisplay);
```

## Log Result

[image]